# How to adjust your dataset so it fits a power-law?

Tags: distributions, power-law, information-retrieval

I have created a dataset of pictures taken at the museum of different paintings. The dataset is divided into 113 different categories (paintings) and contains around 4.8k images.

Just to be clear: these pictures were taken for our research by our team, these images are not taken from users who tested the app (which is still in development). The purpose of this dataset is to test our approach in a realistic way, following a realistic distribution, using realistic devices and taking the images like different users would do. Changing the dataset in such a context is legit and I don't think that there is something wrong with it.

I want that this dataset fits a power-law. In order to do so, I'll check if the log-log plot, where on the *x* axis there bill be the paintings in order of popularity (so *x* = 1 is the most popular painting in the dataset) and *f(x)* will be the fraction of images in the dataset relative to that painting.

Probably, the resulting log-log plot will not be a straight line, so the dataset will probably not fit a power-law distribution.

**I have two questions:**

1. Given the *x*-th most popular painting, how many pictures I have to add/remove so my dataset follows a power-law? The only solution that came to my mind is to draw a trending line represented by *g(x)* and query it for each *x* so I know how many pictures to add/remove for each painting.
2. As alternative, let's suppose that I want that my dataset have 113 categories (so the *x* axis has 113 values) and I want that my dataset has 5k images, how many pictures do I have to take for each category so the resulting dataset fits a power-law?

**Why I need this:**

We are developing a cache for virtual reality applications. It has been proven how the subjects of multimedia applications usually follows a power-law distribution. In our case we are developing two applications: a cinema movie poster recognition *and* a painting recognition. Caches strategies are effective only if the subjects follow a power-law distribution (and so a cache hit is probable). Up to now it doesn't exist such a datasets to simulate our caching strategy (so pictures of paintings/posters taken at the museum/cinema with smartphones following a power-law) so we are creating it (and make it public, it's part of our contribution). I hope this make more clear why I need this.

Comment: Why would you want to modify your dataset so that it fits a particular model? Is this *inverse statistics*?

Comment: I can't go too much in details, but we want to create which fits a power-law distribution to test our library and approach, so adjust it is part of the game :) Is that so uncommon?

Comment: This article discusses the importance of distributional assumptions wrt *any* digitized dataset, clearly distinguishing between gaussian, lognormal and power lawed. It may have relevance for your project, idk... https://ai2-s2-pdfs.s3.amazonaws.com/5ba0/3a03d844f10d7b4861d3b116818afe2b75f2.pdf

Comment: @DJohnson I'm sorry, maybe I didn't understand your comment, but are you suggesting that maybe the power-law distribution is not the right distribution for our dataset? What do you mean for distributional assumptions?

Comment: I have no idea if it's the right distributional assumption or not. There's plenty of literature out there to aid in that determination. The paper cited is one. @olivier 's first question (above) bears reiteration, why do you want to impose a power law on your data in the first place?

Comment: user6321, you're going to be stuck in an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) until you can bring yourself to explain what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I think you're conflating the distinction between *theoretical* and *empirical* distributions. Once you have enough information (data) to make a determination, you can evaluate the fit between the two using any one of a number of distance functions: Kolmogorov, Anderson-Darling, etc. All of this is well covered in Maleverge and Sornette's book *Extreme Financial Risk*. Ignore the "financial" part, for your purposes it's simply an excellent introduction to this issue. In particular, see pps. 61++.

Comment: @DJohnson We have plenty of references which indicates that multimedia applications and any kind of applications with an audience follows a power-law distribution. For example [here](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1331834) it's shown how few photos in Flickr generates most of the views, [here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S030645731000107X) it's shown how clustered CBIR subjects follows a power-law, [here](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1298309) video popularity on YouTube, [here](http://www.digitalmusicnews.com/2014/01/17/nbs/) music streaming.

Comment: @DJohnson [here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1140/epjb/e2004-00382-7) blockbuster movies and [here](https://scholar.google.com/scholar_url?url=http://www3.cs.stonybrook.edu/~leman/courses/12CSE590/readings/kleinber00book_ch18.pdf&hl=en&sa=T&oi=gsb-ggp&ct=res&cd=0&ei=tanoWNHHFoipmAHRl4voBg&scisig=AAGBfm2hERLGzpkbDIkO2Olu9Y4FE4dm6g) "almost everything with an audience"

Comment: Regardless of what happens with similar variables in other data sets, I see no reason to adjust your data.

Comment: @PeterFlom I'm sorry, I've shown how with multiple references that in many different multimedia applications the subjects popularity follows a power-law. In order to make realistic simulations, the dataset used for testing should respect such a distribution. If our dataset doesn't follow this distribution, we have to adjust it. What's wrong with this? :)

Comment: Everything is wrong with it.  You are lying about your data.

Comment: @PeterFlom But this dataset is artificially generated! This is not a dataset taken from people who tested the application, we are creating the dataset! There is no lie such "we have taken query images from the application and seen that it follows a power-law distribution" but "we present a dataset that represents possible query images and it follows a realistic power-law distribution because of the references that I've shown you"

Comment: @PeterFlom I updated the question and added some words to what I've said in last comment. Do you still think that this is wrong?

Comment: @peterflom could have been less blunt (*niceness* is a CV requirement). I still think you are conflating the distinctions between theoretical and empirical distributions. "Power laws" are not defined by a single distribution. In fact, there are many families, classes and subclasses that fall into this broad rubric. Enough so that a large literature with wide disagreement and controversy has built up around the best ways to classify a distribution into one of the power-lawed families. You, the OP, need to obtain a deeper familiarity with this lit before you do anything else.

Comment: @DJohnson ok but there is nothing wrong in changing such a dataset, right? Since its purpose is to test and evaluate an approach, it's legit to change it so it fits as best as possible the desired distribution (regardless of that that is), don't you think?

Comment: It is wrong to change the dataset this way.

Comment: @PeterFlom I appreciate that you're contributing, but you're not giving reasons about because this is wrong. It's not very constructive, I'm sorry.

Comment: Your question has had over 50 views, 10+ comments and *zero* responses. This should tell you something...like your question isn't making any sense to CV participants. To me, it sounds like you're in over your head with this analysis. However, I will grant that you are nothing if not persistent.

Comment: I tend to agree or sympathize with all comments so far. Regardless, your numbered questions look unanswerable to me. How could we possibly answer them except by knowing your data and then ourselves carrying out numeric experiments on different strategies? Even simpler analogues of the same (e.g. I have non-normal data. How many points do I need to remove to make it approximately normal?) are not answerable. The question is on all fours with how much string do I need? You have evidently can't show us the data (sounds enormous in any case) but that leaves you in a bind. Sorry.